# Run Specific Tests with Ant Deploy specified by command line or file

Tags: deployment, ant, migration-tool, ci, ant-script

When deploying with ant you have the option to specify which tests to run, e.g.

```
<target name="deploy">
<sf:deploy username="${sf.username}"
           password="${sf.password}"
           serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
           deployRoot="${dir}"
           testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests"
           maxPoll="300">
   <runTest>Test1</runTest>
   <runTest>Test2</runTest>
</sf:deploy>
```

We use a shared build script with the team and I'm trying to figure out how to pass a list of tests to run during the deployment from either a file or a parameter. Ideally we could do `ant deploy -Dtests=Test1,Test2`

I'm a very novice ant users, and I'm really struggling to figure out how to accomplish this.

I'd thought this might work and then I could hook up the list value to a command line parameter, but it complains that `sf:deploy` doesn't support a nested `for` element.

```
<target name="mydeploy">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}"
             password="${sf.password}"
             serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
             deployRoot="${dir}"
             testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests"
             maxPoll="300">
      <for list="Test1,Test2" param="test">
        <sequential>
            <runTest>"@{test}"</runTest>
        </sequential>
      </for>
  </sf:deploy>
</target>
```

Is there anyway to build the list of `<runTest>` elements dynamically based on a command line input or file so that I don't need to edit my `build.xml` script everytime I want to do a deploy with a subset of tests?

Perhaps I should just be abandoning ant in favor of something like grunt?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Was able to do this using ant's scripting capability. Now you can do `ant deploy -Ddir=src -Dtests=Class1,Class2,Class3`

```
<target name="deploy">
  <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
    var deployTask = project.createTask('antlib:com.salesforce:deploy');
    deployTask.setUsername(project.getProperty("sf.username"));
    deployTask.setPassword(project.getProperty("sf.password"));
    deployTask.setServerURL(project.getProperty("sf.serverurl"));
    deployTask.setDeployRoot(project.getProperty("dir"));
    deployTask.setTestLevel(project.getProperty("testLevel"));
    deployTask.setMaxPoll("300");
    var tests = project.getProperty('tests');
    if (tests) {
      deployTask.setTestLevel('RunSpecifiedTests');
      tests = tests.split(',');
      for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
        var runTest = java.lang.Class.forName(
          "com.salesforce.ant.DeployTask$CodeNameElement"
        ).newInstance();
        runTest.addText(tests[i]);
        deployTask.addRunTest(runTest);
      }
    }
    deployTask.perform();
  ]]></script>
</target>
```

Comment: That's great. Even I was also looking for something like this. +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't  have enough reputation to comment, but I wanted to say Ralph Callaway's solution worked perfectly for me. I expanded it slightly to cover a few more of the Salesforce Migration Tool's parameters. I thought I'd share that here, and also give props to Ralph:

```
<target name="deployDynamic">
    <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
        var deployTask = project.createTask('antlib:com.salesforce:deploy');
        deployTask.setUsername(project.getProperty("sf.username"));
        deployTask.setPassword(project.getProperty("sf.password"));
        deployTask.setServerURL(project.getProperty("sf.serverurl"));
        deployTask.setDeployRoot(project.getProperty("directory"));
        deployTask.setTestLevel(project.getProperty("testLevel"));
        deployTask.setSinglePackage(project.getProperty("singlePackage"));
        deployTask.setIgnoreWarnings(project.getProperty("ignoreWarnings"));
        deployTask.setAutoUpdatePackage(project.getProperty("autoUpdatePackage"));
        deployTask.setAllowMissingFiles(project.getProperty("allowMissingFiles"));
        deployTask.setCheckonly(project.getProperty("checkOnly"));
        deployTask.setMaxPoll("10000");
        var tests = project.getProperty('tests');
        if (tests) {
            deployTask.setTestLevel('RunSpecifiedTests');
            tests = tests.split(',');
            var CodeNameElement = deployTask.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("com.salesforce.ant.DeployTask$CodeNameElement");

            for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
                var runTest = CodeNameElement.newInstance();
                runTest.addText(tests[i]);
                deployTask.addRunTest(runTest);
            }
        }
        deployTask.perform();
    ]]></script>
</target>
```

Comment: this counts as answer imo, although in this sort of case you might consider improving the original answer by editing it, even with very low rep you can edit questions, the edits just have to get reviewed.

Comment: Update: this was working great on a self-hosted Jenkins instance. We are now moving to Github with self-hosted task runners in EC2. For some reason now, Ant/Salesforce plugin is acting differently, and using the "deployDynamic" task defined in my answer here, I am now getting:

`BUILD FAILED
/home/ec2-user/actions-runner/_work/chg-fox-monolith/chg-fox-monolith/jenkinsFiles/build.xml:68: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.salesforce.ant.DeployTask$CodeNameElement
 at 
... etc...
`
Any ideas ? @RalphCallaway

Comment: I finally figured out that issue. I think it was an Oracle JDK vs OpenJDK issue. I essentially had to change `java.lang.Class.forName("com.salesforce.ant.DeployTask$CodeNameElement")` to `deployTask.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("com.salesforce.ant.DeployTask$CodeNameElement")`. I'm going to update my code in the answer to reflect.