# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.salesforce.ant.DeployTask$CodeNameElement

Tags: unit-test, deployment, error, ant, migration

I'm trying to implement running a list of tests as per this link 
[Run Specific Tests with Ant Deploy specified by command line or file](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164619/run-specific-tests-with-ant-deploy-specified-by-command-line-or-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

and passing the list of tests as a parameter  ${tests}, but am getting the error :

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.salesforce.ant.DeployTask$CodeNameElement

below is the snippet of the build file :

```
<target name="deployChrisDevCodeSpecify" >
     <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
            var deployTask = project.createTask('antlib:com.salesforce:deploy');
            deployTask.setUsername(project.getProperty("sf.username"));
            deployTask.setPassword(project.getProperty("sf.password"));
            deployTask.setServerURL(project.getProperty("sf.serverurl"));
            deployTask.setDeployRoot(project.getProperty("dir"));
            deployTask.setTestLevel("RunSpecifiedTests");
            deployTask.setMaxPoll("300");
            var tests = "${tests}" ;
            if (tests) {
              deployTask.setTestLevel('RunSpecifiedTests');
              tests = tests.split(',');
              for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
                var runTest = java.lang.Class.forName(
                  "com.salesforce.ant.DeployTask$CodeNameElement"
                ).newInstance();
                runTest.addText(tests[i]);
                deployTask.addRunTest(runTest);
              }
            }
            deployTask.perform();
          ]]></script>
</target>
```

Is there a java file/library that it may be referencing that is missing which i need to download?

note : I've tried declaring the tests in the script rather than passing as a parameter and still get the same error.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you downloaded Salesforce ANT migration tool jar? [Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_install.htm)

Comment: yes - been using the migration tool for a while for tests and deployment via jenkins, just can't get the above script to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it looks to me, the ant script is not finding the ant-salesforce.jar and classes in the package correctly.

You should add it while running the class or create a classpath task inside of ant script.

Below code should work for you while running ant

`ant deploy -Ddir=src -Dtests=Class1,Class2,Class3 -lib ant-salesforce.jar`

Please note that `ant-salesforce.jar` was in the same folder as build xml.